# Traverse a path to reach a resource in diffrent directory

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

[image]

What would be the exact path to get my header-logo.png in header.vue file.

In header.vue file I tried `background-image: url('./../resources/images/header-logo.png')` or  `background-image: url('./.././resources/images/header-logo.png')` or some other options as well but it is not able to locate to the image.

If I can get explanation as well then it would be more helpful.

Comment: You will have to look in the `dist` folder. Your transpilation step most likely doesn't respect the file system structure of your source code.

Answer (score 0):

```
background-image: url('../.././resources/images/header-logo.png')
```

Should work, also the transpilation will map it so no need to point to your dis file.
Remember `./` is at the same level, where `../` takes you one up, you need to go up to `src/` then up to `account-app` then into `account-app/resources...`.